# deleting a hash table in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, hashtable

I am building a hash table using arrays and buckets that are represented by linked lists in C++. I am running into something very weird when I try to clear the hash table and I would appreciate it if someone can explain why this is happening.

This code works fine:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bins; i++)
{
    while(map[i]->next != nullptr)
    {
        LN* toDelete = map[i];
        map[i] = map[i]->next;
        delete toDelete;
    }
}
```

However for some reason if I do this, it doesn't delete anything anymore:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bins; i++)
{
    LN* node = map[i]
    while(node->next != nullptr)
    {
        LN* toDelete = node;
        node = node->next;
        delete toDelete;
    }
}
```

Each bucker is represented by a trailer linked list that's why I'm checking node->next not node. From my okay understanding of pointers, node should refer to the same thing as `map[i]` so when I call delete on node it should delete the object that both `map[i]` and node refer to.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I assume you're doing this hash-table as an exercise? Otherwise you should be using [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Your code (both examples) doesn't delete *all* nodes, it will not delete the last node.

Comment: It's a trailer linked list so it's fine if it leaves the trailer in place

Comment: What happens if `map [0]` is `nullptr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does delete everything. What it doesn't do is changing `map[i]` pointer to point to an empty list element (with `next` set to `nullptr`) at the end, so it ends up pointing to a deleted object.

This means that `map[i]` is *dangling*. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior. This can be fixed by assigning `map[i]` the value of `node` after the loop:

```
LN* node = map[i];
while(node->next != nullptr)
{
    LN* toDelete = node;
    node = node->next;
    delete toDelete;
}
map[i] = node;
```

Comment: Each bucket is represented by a trailer linkedlist so if no values were present in the bucket map[i] should point to an empty node. I think what I wasnt clear about is that this code isn't implemented in the destructor, it is used to clear the contents of the linked list. My question is would saying that node* = map[i] be the same as using map[i]. For some reason the second block of code in my question doesn't run as expected.